# Form not valid in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am trying to process a form in Symfony2, I get all the values from it in the controller, but when I call:

```
$form->isValid()
```

it returns false. I am trying to process the form in a different Controller.

The form is rendered in two pieces, first some personal data and then some more information, but in the submit event of the form, I join all values serializing the forms. This is how I render the form in the view:

```
<form id="myform" action="{{ path('_process_my_form') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.first_name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}} ) }}
  ... // then I render the rest of the personal information widgets
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="myform2">
  {{ form_widget(form.job_name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}} ) }}
  ... // then I render the rest of the widgets (not personal information)
</form>
```

Then, in the Ajax request, I join the two forms like this:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: e.target.method,
    url: e.target.action,
    data: $("#my_form").serialize() + $("#my_form2").serialize(),
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {},
    success: function(data) {
      //do something...
    }
  });
});
```

My _process_my_form rule looks like this:

```
_process_my_form:
    pattern:   /ajax/process-my-form
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:User:processMyForm }
```

This is the Controller who controls the Ajax request:

```
public function processMyFormAction(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
  {
    $myEntity = new myEntity();
    $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new myFormType(), $myEntity);
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
      //Process the form... this code is never excecuted :(
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong???

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of Symfony 2.3 I believe they changed the form handle from

```
$form->bind($request);
```

to

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

However I'm not sure if the former is still supported? As far as I can see, the bind method not longer exists in the [Form Interface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html)

You can read more here [Symfony Cookbook - Form Direct Submit](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html)

Comment: Additionally, you cannot have two forms submitted in that manner.
You will need to wrap all form inputs in the **same set of form tags**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test it when I get home, but the cool thing is that I am able to get all the values from both forms in my Controller, and also, I ignored the $form->isValid() and tried to store the values in the Database and worked! So, I will let you know when I test your answer. Thanks!